# C Programming - function squeeze(s1,s2) that deletes each character in s1 that matches character in s2

Tags: c

So this is the program that I created:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void squeeze_1(char s[],char q[])
{
    int i, j, k;

    for (k=0; q[k] != '\0'; k++)
    {
        for ( i = j = 0; s[i] != '\0'; i++, j++)
        {
            if (s[i] != q[k])
                s[j] = s[i];
        }
    }
    s [j] = '\0';
    return 0;
}

void main (void)
{
    char s[] = "I hate computer science";
    char q[] = "co";

    squeeze_1(s,q);
    printf("%s", &s);
    return 0;
}
```

This program does not work at all. I really cannot find any mistakes. However, when I change the for loop to:

```
for ( i = j = 0 ; s[i] != '\0' ; i++)
{
    if (s[i] != q[k])
        s[++j] = s[i];
}
```

I will get the output that is **almost correct, which is "I hate mputer scienence" It is exactly the output. I am not sure where the "enen" comes from....

It would be great if any of you could tell me what I have done wrong.

Comment: It also appears that you hate debuggers too. (You need to insert a `\0` in the changed string.)

Comment: Maybe your computer dislikes the text? Seriously: use the debugger and step through your code. Debugging is the major part of programming and this Is a good lesson.

Comment: I tried to use the debuggers but it didn't say anything.... @Bathsheba what do you mean by inserting a \0 in the changed string??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that your for loop always increments j so that the `\0` will stay at the end of the full array and not be put at the end of the compressed array

```
for ( i = j = 0; s[i] != '\0'; i++, j++)
```

means that if `s[i] == q[k]` and it is not copied into `s[j]`, then j should **not** be incremented (but you do increment it anyway). This is what you are doing in the version that almost works. However, since you start j at 0 (with i) then it should be

```
for ( i = j = 0 ; s[i] != '\0' ; i++)
{
    if (s[i] != q[k])
    {
        s[j++] = s[i];
        s[j] = `\0`
    }
 }
```

Doing this will also put the `\0` in at the correct place.

You might also have a somewhat better loop as

```
#include <stdlib.h>

void squeeze_1(char s[],char q[])
{
    int i, j, k;
    int found = 0;

    for ( i = j = 0; s[i] != '\0'; i++, j++)
    {
        for (k=0; q[k] != '\0'; k++)
        {
            if (s[i] == q[k])
                found = 1
        }
        if (!found)
        {
            s[j++] = s[i];
            s [j] = '\0';
        }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi, in my program I now have  s[j++] = s[i]. However, the output is still "I hate mputer scienence". I am not sure why. :(

Comment: Check the value of j that you use to put the final `\0` in on and make sure that you are putting it in correctly.

Comment: Thank you so much :) It really helps haha.

Comment: @Justin It might be better to make the loop over q the inside loop as that would be faster since it is looping over fewer elements. If this is what you want click the accept button.

Answer (score 0):

You have to end the string earlier after all non matching chars have been copied

After your (inner) *for* loop, add

```
s[j] = '\0';
```

That gives

```
for ( i = j = 0 ; s[i] != '\0' ; i++)
{
    if (s[i] != q[k])
        s[++j] = s[i];
}

s[j] = 0; // <=== here
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Your comment makes so much sense and I immediately get it. :) There was a typo. I think it should be s[j] = '\0' ;  :) Like you said earlier

Comment: Actually `char c = 0;` and `char c = '\0';` are the same. A *char* in C is a 8-bits integer.